# Mark specific words with asterisks (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have an array of objects with a set of certain words like entities. For example :

```
footnotes: [
  { sourceText: 'red'},
  { sourceText: 'green'},
  { sourceText: 'yellow'},
  { sourceText: 'purple'},
  { sourceText: 'gray'},
  { sourceText: 'blue'}
]
```

And I have some random sentences. For example: 'I drive a red car among green fields and look at the gray sky'

The goal is to mark words with asterisks according to the object of entities:

'I drive a red* car among green** fields and look at the gray*** sky'

I'm trying to do this in a loop with silce and Regexp but I can't concatenate the string correctly

How can this be done ?

Here is my code

```
footnotes = [{
    sourceText: "red",
    solve: false
  },
  {
    sourceText: "green",
    solve: false
  },
  {
    sourceText: 'yellow',
    solve: false
  },
  {
    sourceText: "purple",
    solve: false
  },
  {
    sourceText: "grey",
    solve: false
  },
  {
    sourceText: "blue",
    solve: false
  }
]

starGenerate = function(count) {
  let result = ''
  
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result += '*'
  }
  
  return result
},


let post = {
  id: 21321,
  data: {},
  lead: 'I drive a red car among green fields and look at the gray sky'
}


post.check = function() {
  let str, concat = ''
  let self = this;
  let starcounter = 0

  for (let i = 0; i < self.entities.length; i++) {
    let reg = new RegExp(`${self.entities[i].sourceText}`);

    if (match = reg.exec(self.lead) && self.entities[i].solve === false) {
      concat = self.lead.replace(reg, `${self.entities[i].sourceText + starGenerate(++starcounter)}`)
      self.entities[i].solve = true
    }
  }
}

post.entities = footnotes
```

Comment: You seem to have an errant comma after your function. Why is the function a property of the post object? How is it called? You might simplify and put that code in a snippet demo using the editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with one regular expression (using `|`), and then use the callback argument of `replace` to insert the asterisks. I would prepare the replacement text for each word and place it in an object keyed by word. Your function `starGenerate` is not really needed, as there is the [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method.

```js
function putAsterisks(footnotes, sentence) {
    let alternatives = footnotes.map(({sourceText}) => sourceText).join("|");
    let replacements = Object.fromEntries(footnotes.map(({sourceText}, i) => 
        [sourceText, sourceText + "*".repeat(i + 1)]
    ));
    let regex = RegExp("\\b(" + alternatives + ")\\b", "gi");
    return sentence.replace(regex, m => replacements[m]);
}

// Example:
let footnotes = [{ sourceText: 'red'}, { sourceText: 'green'}, { sourceText: 'yellow'}, { sourceText: 'purple'}, { sourceText: 'gray'}, { sourceText: 'blue'}];
let sentence = 'I drive a red car among green fields and look at the gray sky with a red moon';

console.log(putAsterisks(footnotes, sentence));
```

This assumes that the source texts do not contain characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions. If this could happen, then use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/5459839) to first escape those words.

Comment: I'd assume OP wants "I have a red* t-shirt and I drive a red* car among green** fields..." but it's not specified and the change is trivial anyway so my +1!

Comment: Thanks @AdrianoRepetti, that's a good remark. I have updated the code to use a number of stars that reflects the footnote sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same without regex by splitting your string and using `map` among all the words. This works fine as long as there is no further punctuation in your input string

```js
const footnotes=[{sourceText:"red",solve:!1},{sourceText:"green",solve:!1},{sourceText:"yellow",solve:!1},{sourceText:"purple",solve:!1},{sourceText:"grey",solve:!1},{sourceText:"blue",solve:!1}];

const input = 'I drive a red car among green fields and look at the grey sky'
const footnotesIndex = footnotes.reduce( (acc,i) => (acc[i.sourceText] = i.solve,acc),{});
let star=1
const result = input.split(" ").map( word =>footnotesIndex[word] != undefined ? word + "*".repeat(star++) : word).join(" ");
console.log(result);
```